# Preloading images with Prototype/Scriptaculous

Tags: javascript, image, prototypejs, scriptaculous, preload

I'm using Prototype/Scriptaculous library for a featured content slider, it works great but the images need to be preloaded.

I've used jQuery mostly so I'm not sure how its done with Prototype. Here's the [slider script](http://jsfiddle.net/vy8By/) if you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a few simple lines of Javascript

```
var preload = []
for(var x=0;x<slider_images.length;x++) {
     preload[x] = new Image()
     preload[x].src = slider_images[x]
}
```